# Where do I find the databases? Visual Studio and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I have installed Visual Studio Ultimate, and installed the Microsoft SQL Server, and tried to find my way around it, using some tutorials I found on line.
I have successfully compiled and run the following C# code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            sql.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE newDatabase;", sql);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE newTable (name VARCHAR(20), age INT)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO newTable VALUES ('John', 29)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO newTable VALUES ('Jack', 21)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO newTable VALUES ('Robin', 22)";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM newTable;";
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} years old.",reader.GetString(0), reader.GetValue(1));
            }

            reader.Close();
            sql.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

This will produce the right output, but now I want to actually **see** the `newDatabase` data-base. So I search for the keyword 'sql', and found the 'Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio', and opened it.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find my database there under Databases:
[image]
Where is it hiding and how can I find it?

Comment: have you right clicked `Databases` and hit Refresh?

Comment: Your commands apart from the create database are executed against the MASTER database. Try to expand the System Databases

Comment: I have tried it, and there's no change.
Funny thing is that I searched my hard drive for `newDatabase` and found out it sits at `C:\Users\**my_user_name**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS` (as an `.mdf` file). Is it possible I have two copies of SQL on my PC that might cause this confusion? (because I remember that I installed it and then reinstalled it...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach this new database. On `Databases`, "right-click", and attach Database. Browse to the C# project folder defined when you created your project with visual studio and you will find it in the folder.

### Update

In case you want to define the path directly to avoid searching you can have look on this example which might help you:

```
  String str;
  SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

  str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
       "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
       "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
       "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
       "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
       "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
       "SIZE = 1MB, " +
       "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
       "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
  try 
  {
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

   }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());
  }
  finally
  {
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
    myConn.Close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I right-clicked it and chose 'attach', and got new "Attach Databases" window. I then clicked "Add.." and a navigate widow opened up. I then tried to navigate to my VS C# project path, but couldn't (it won't expand the `c:\users\**my_username**` folder. so, I tried to navigate my VS C# project path through the Windows Explorer window (the usual way of navigating folders in Windows), and found out that the folder `c:\users\**my_username**` icon has a lock image on it. I guess this is why it won't let me expand it when trying to navigate it through the "Attach Databases" window.

Comment: nevertheless, my C# project folder has no `.mdf` file in it... though I found my `.mdf` file at `C:\Users\**my_user_name**\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS` for some reason...

Comment: Sure you right, as you didn't precise the path I presume.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, are you saying the path is wrong?

Comment: OK, so the Update you added to your post will enable me to navigate to the .mdf file and attach it?